# Report initial value to parent Vue container

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I implemented radio button input as Vue container:

```html
<template lang='pug'>
    each v in [ 1, 500, 1000 ]
        input( v-model='value', value=v )
        label( for=v )
</template>
<script lang='ts'>
    export default {
        data : ()=>{
            value : 500 as Number,
        },
        watch : {
            value : {
                handler( newVal : string ) {
                    this.$emit( 'input', parseInt( newVal ) )
                },
                deep : true,
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Which I use in other container like this:

```html
<template lang='pug'>
    Picker( v-model='options' )
</template>
<script lang='ts'>
export default Vue.extend({    
    methods:{
        do_something() {
            console.log( 'Has no data until Picker clicked by user at least once:', this.options )
        }
    },
    data : () => ({
        options : Number,
    }),
})
</script>
```

But parent container won't receive any data from child until radio button will be actually used by user. How can I receive initial data as well? Tried `mounted()` method but `this.$emit` isn't available there yet.

P.S. Also, is there any hack to somehow reuse the same constant `500` from `[1, 500, 1000]` when setting initial `value : 500 as Number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the *ref* attribute: [Accessing Child Component Instances & Child Elements](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements)

However, consider reversing the logic, rather than accessing the values from the parent component, **set** them from the parent component through the use of props.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Reading docs about `$ref` indeed reveals it's mostly just a hack, but in my real app I have many components which have complicated data which I intend to reuse over multiple parents and setting all those (repeating) data every time I use them looks way more ugly.